# Contact set is relatively closed

Tags: general-topology

Going through the notion of an upper contact set, that is
$$
    \Gamma^+_u = \left\{ y \in \Omega\mid \exists P_y \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \text{s.t. } u(x) \leq u(y) +P_y \cdot (x-y) \ \forall x \in \Omega \right\}
$$
for a function $u \in C^0(\Omega)$, some authors claim something like, if $\Omega$ is bounded then $\Gamma^+$ is relatively closed in $\Omega$.

It sounds intuitive, but how can i show this?

Answer (score 0):

$\quad \quad$First we regard $\Omega$ as a topological space and assign its subspace topology.(i.e. ($\Omega$,$\mathscr{T}$),$\mathscr{T}$={$\Omega \cap U$|U is a open set of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$}).

$\quad \quad$ And we know $u \in C^{0}(\Omega)$,this is a continuous  mapping from topological space $\Omega$ to topological space $\mathbb{R}$.
$$u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$$$u(\Gamma_{+})=[min\{u(x)-p_{y}\cdot (x-y)\},max\{u\}]$$This depends on $u(x)-p_{y}\cdot (x-y) \in C^{0}(\Omega)$,so by the definition of continuous function of topological space and $u(\Gamma_{+})$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.So the original image set $$\Gamma_{+}=u^{-1}(\Gamma_{+})$$is relatively closed.
I think this result is far-fetched and hope someone can give the correct answer！